# java string match pattern with a-z , A-Z, 0-9 and some special char

Tags: java, string

I need to write a method which match a-z, A-Z , 0-9 and some special charecter like . , @, _, -.

I have written but confused with spcl characters.

```
public static boolean isAlfaNumeric(String src) {
    if (src == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (src.matches("[a-zA-z0-9]*")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  -

```
public static boolean isAlfaNumeric(String src) {
    if (src == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (src.matches("[\\w@,-]*")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Put the required special characters inside the square brackets.
For your info - **\w** covers all the word characters which includes alphabets in both cases, digits and underscore character.
Hope this is helpful.